# spotify api module Cannot resolve symbol from

Tags: java, android

[what is happening?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCMrg.jpg)

I tried Invalidating the cache and restarting it many times, deleted the .idea folder, imported only the aar file, and added the module... I would love some help if anyone could help me out with that! Many thanks! It is worth mentioning that I am also using the Spotify-auth library which is working fine!

My Project:app file:

```
 buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.5.0'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.10"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.9, 0.99.99]'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My Module:app file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
   id 'kotlin-android'

}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.songout"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs{
        debug{
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword ''
            storeFile file('C:\\Users\\elton\\.android\\debug-keystore.jks')
            storePassword ''
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug{
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    //http requests and queue manager library
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    //This library handles authorization and authentication (please do not update the version and always use 1.1.0)
    implementation 'com.spotify.android:auth:1.1.0'
    // This library handles music playback
    implementation (':spotify-app-remote-release-0.7.0')
}
```

Comment: There's no import in your code for that class, and there's no class with that name in your current package, so I'm not sure what you're expecting here.

Comment: every time I try to add the import it says it cannot find a symbol and Android Studio automatically deletes it. I am trying to call the class from the Spotify API module

Comment: So (sorry if this seems obvious, but it's not clear from your picture) if you write `import com.spotify.android.appremote.api.SpotifyAppRemote;` Android Studio gives an error?

Comment: And sorry if I state the obvious again, but are you following [these instructions](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/#create-your-app)?

Comment: sorry about the picture, was just a print screen hahaha so yes if I do that it gives an error cannot find symbol even though the module is installed. Thanks a lot for the help, I am kinda desperate here. I am following the instructions from their official website :)

Comment: To be perfectly honest, my help ends here because I'm out of ideas already :( sorry. I hope someone that has more familiarity with Android then I have can help you further.

Comment: You-re amazing man! thank you for taking the time, it is not a straightforward issue but I hope we can get this sorted and help others in the future. Many thanks!

Comment: Shot in the dark, just comparing the docs to your post - do you need to include the `project` directive `implementation project(':spotify-app-remote')` (from the documentation site)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys, I really appreciate it! after struggling a bit with that and reinstalling the module again and again I got a solution for my problem.
So basically what you have to do is:

- delete the module, .idea folder, and then run an Invalidate Caches/Restart;
- before re-installing the module keep the `implementation project(':spotify-app-remote')` on your Gradle files;
- right-click on the app folder and choose New-> Module;
- choose import .jar/aar package (if you import the module via the file menu it will never work don't ask me why hahaha)
- rename the module name to `:spotify-app-remote` and hit finish;

Android Studio still has some bugs with importing modules that do not come from the gradle archives, so I hope they will have a better look at that in the future.